# How to add the fixed width and height to the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, tooltip

I have designed a tooltip custom menu which shows the different tooltip messages, currently, it works as expected and I have developed using the `Tailwind CSS` based on the reference from the Google Chrome inspect feature which displays the tooltip when we inspect any element.

I would like to apply the fixed width and height to it so if the content in the tooltip menu is large then it should not stretch based on the content rather it should add a scrollbar. I tried adding the `max-w` and `w-` etc but for some reason, it does not work and width is not taken into consideration due to which it stretches based on the content.

How to fix the issue with width and height for the tooltip menu so it remains constant even for the large content in the tooltip. Following is the code I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center bg-gray-100">
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-12 items-center">
      <div
        data-tip="Hello Tooltip 1"
        class="relative before:absolute before:content-[attr(data-tip)] before:px-3 before:py-2 before:left-1/2 before:-top-3 before:w-max before:max-w-xs before:-translate-x-1/2 before:-translate-y-full before:bg-gray-700 before:text-white before:rounded-md before:opacity-0 before:transition-all after:absolute after:left-1/2 after:-top-3 after:h-0 after:w-0 after:-translate-x-1/2 after:border-8 after:border-t-gray-700 after:border-l-transparent after:border-b-transparent after:border-r-transparent after:opacity-0 after:transition-all hover:before:opacity-100 hover:after:opacity-100"
      >
        <p>Two</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Google Chromes inspect feature, something similar what I am looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've create a div with class **max-w-xs** and **max-h-40** around your tooltip content. You can make changes as per your need

```
<template>
  <div class="flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center bg-gray-100">
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-12 items-center">
      <div
        data-tip="Hello Tooltip 1"
        class="relative before:absolute before:content-[attr(data-tip)] before:px-3 before:py-2 before:left-1/2 before:-top-3 before:w-max before:max-w-xs before:-translate-x-1/2 before:-translate-y-full before:bg-gray-700 before:text-white before:rounded-md before:opacity-0 before:transition-all after:absolute after:left-1/2 after:-top-3 after:h-0 after:w-0 after:-translate-x-1/2 after:border-8 after:border-t-gray-700 after:border-l-transparent after:border-b-transparent after:border-r-transparent after:opacity-0 after:transition-all hover:before:opacity-100 hover:after:opacity-100"
      >
        <div class="max-w-xs max-h-40 overflow-auto"> <!-- max-h is added -->
          <p>Two</p> <!-- Add tooltip content here -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```